# Regex for picking a Value After “=”

Tags: javascript, regex

How i can select RQR-1BN6Q360090-0001 (without quotes) using Regex in below -

```
<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="/gaits/CreateReport.aspx?RptNum=RQR-1BN6Q360090-0001">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>

I tried this but it does  not work
RptNum=([A-Za-z]+)$
```

Comment: Use `/RptNum=([\w-]+)/`

Comment: It returns RptNum=RQR-1BN6Q360090-0001, i need RQR-1BN6Q360090-0001

Comment: No, `s.match(/RptNum=([\w-]+)/)[1]` does what you need

Comment: Thanks , it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
/RptNum=([\w-]+)/
```

The pattern will match `RptNum=` and then capture 1 or more occurrences of word chars (letters, digits and `_`) or hyphens. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ovc3AN/1) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=RptNum%3D(%5B%5Cw-%5D%2B)):

[image]

Note that

```
/RptNum=([A-Z0-9-]+)/
```

might be a more restrictive pattern that should work, too. It does not match `_` and lowercase letters.

In JS, use it with `String#match()` and grab the second array item upon a match:

```js
var s = 'Object moved to <a href="/gaits/CreateReport.aspx?RptNum=RQR-1BN6Q360090-0001">here</a>';
var m = s.match(/RptNum=([\w-]+)/);
if (m) {
  console.log(m[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, we can also use an expression that collects the new lines, such as:

```
[\s\S]*RptNum=(.+?)"[\s\S]*
[\w\W]*RptNum=(.+?)"[\w\W]*
[\d\D]*RptNum=(.+?)"[\d\D]*
```

and our desired output is saved in `(.+?)`.

#### Test

```js
const regex = /[\s\S]*RptNum=(.+?)"[\s\S]*/gm;
const str = `<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="/gaits/CreateReport.aspx?RptNum=RQR-1BN6Q360090-0001">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>`;
const subst = `$1`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log(result);
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ym9KeD/1/)

#### RegEx

If this expression wasn't desired, it can be modified/changed in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/Ym9KeD/1/).

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```js
const text = 'RptNum=RQR-1BN6Q360090-0001';

console.log(text.match(/RptNum=.*/).map(m => m.match(/RptNum=.*/)[0])[0].split('RptNum=')[1]);
```

I suppose that works